# A space has been created after applying 'fitsSystemWindows' in some devices. How can I remove it?

Tags: android, android-layout

In the app, I have `status bar` and hide `the bottom control bar`.

Last time, I used `marginTop="20dp"` to fits the under line of status bar. However, I tested out with `Galaxy 10` And the status bar is very different. So, My app looked weird, And solved the problem with applying this attribute at the root view.

```
fitsSystemWindows = "true"
```

However, Now, I have another problem, that the `bottom control bar` is hid but there's empty space as big as the bottom control bar after applying the attribute. Is there any way to fits the screen that shows status bar and no bottom control bar(While I hide it)?

[image]

(Yellow one is MainActivity and Black one is Fragment)

The pink part must reach the bottom, but it can't reach because of that attribute.

I tested and I think just happens with `kitkat` and `Q`.

When I remove that attribute it works with the bottom control bar, but not the status bar...

this is my layout file.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.main.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        ...
    />
    ...
</FrameLayout>
```

So, I use only one `Activity` which has lots of `Fragments`.

And this is what Activity use:

```
    private fun hideStatusBar() {
        DisplayUtil.hideStatusBar(this)
        this?.window?.decorView?.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener { visibility ->
            if (visibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN == 0) {
                DisplayUtil.hideStatusBar(this)
            }
        }
    }

    object DisplayUtil {
        fun hideStatusBar(activity: Activity?) {
            activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY // hide status bar and nav bar after a short delay, or if the user interacts with the middle of the screen
                    )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code snippet that you have tried.

Comment: added the layout. @Sunny

Comment: it's Just FrameLayout. Not enough to know the issue if possible please add screenshot how it looks and how you want to implement

Comment: That's all. It's the layout behaviour. I added the picture.

Comment: I'm currently writing an answer for your question but to give a complete answer I need to know how you're setting views to be underneath or in the system bars area. Are you using `windowTranslucentStatus` theme property or `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` ui flag?

Comment: I've tried creating a small app that has all the code you provided but I'm not able to reproduce your issue. With fitsSystemWindows="true" and the same systemUi flags the top views avoid the status bar area but the bottom views do not avoid the navigation bar area. I tried this on an API 19 and 29 emulator as you said this was happening on kitkat and Q

Comment: @SubaruTashiro I guess, it is because of fragments. Did you also create them? And I don't know if it is OS problem or Device problem. `YotaPhone2` And `Pixel2(emulator)` with API 29 occurred the problem and also HAWEI Phone.

Comment: @c-an I think your best course of action is to find the most minimum amount of code that reproduces this issue consistently on an emulator. Sorry I couldn't help.